# Where can I find the Rif's commentary on tractate Niddah?

Tags: jewish-books, talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, rif-rabbi-isaac-alfasi, maseches-niddah

Where inside tractate *Nidda* can I find [R' Isaac Alfasi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Alfasi)'s commentary on the tractate? I looked in hebrewbooks.org's 685-page [tractate-*Niddah* PDF](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/40053) but couldn't find it.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are only interested in viewing the commentary in this particular pdf file on Hebrewbooks.org, or can this question be broadened (eg "Where is the Rif on Niddah? I can't find it at the end of the Masechta where I expect it to be, but I'm using Hebrewbooks.org, so maybe it's an error in the file. Does anyone know if it's printed in a standard Sha"s?")

Comment: @SethJ: Point taken. Question edited. Thank you.

Comment: Related question: [Why is the Rif's digest of tractate Niddah hidden in tractate Shevuos?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25951/why-is-the-rifs-digest-of-tractate-niddah-hidden-in-tractate-shevuos)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

R' Alfasi's laws of Niddah are actually hidden in the second chapter of tractate *Shevuos*. If you don't have a printed tractate handy, then see pages [767](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37969&pgnum=767) through [778](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37969&pgnum=767) of hebrewbooks.org's [Sanhedrin-Makkos-Shevuos PDF](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/37969).

As a courtesy to the reader ש”ס נהרדעא also includes a second copy of R' Alfasi's laws of Niddah inside tractate *Niddah*. This second copy is not typeset as nicely. You can find it on pages [283](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40053&pgnum=283) through [294](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40053&pgnum=294) of [hebrewbooks.org's PDF](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/40053).

Comment: Are PDF pages [283](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40053&pgnum=283) through [294](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40053&pgnum=294) of [ש”ס נהרדעא: מסכת נדה](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/40053) really the Rif's digest of the entire tractate? The tractate is not a short one.

Comment: @tealhill It says in your link to page 283 that the text they print is originally from Shevuot but was copied there as a favor to the one learning. As for your second point, it is not a short tractate, but most of it discusses things which are not relevant nowadays regarding ritual impurity and the like.