# Why is the Rif's digest of tractate Niddah hidden in tractate Shevuos?

Tags: jewish-books, talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, rif-rabbi-isaac-alfasi, maseches-niddah

[Rabbi Isaac Alfasi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Alfasi)'s summary of tractate *Niddah* is [hidden in masechet *Shevuot*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25943/where-can-i-find-the-rifs-commentary-on-tractate-niddah). Why is it buried in maseches *Shevuos*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not all in Shevuot, there is some in Yevamot. I think the reason is that there is only about one or two perakim that are הלכה למעשה (like הרואה כתם) in Niddah, so the Rif wrote down the halachos thereof on masechtos that he was writing on anyway that have sugyas related to Niddah, like the end of the second perek of Shevuot.

Comment: +1.  But didn't he know that would make things more confusing for readers of his digest (_Sefer HaHalachos_)?

Comment: the rif's halachos were originally written/printed as a separate sefer, so they were all together anyway. also, they only question is why he didn't write on maseches nidda. other than that, it is perfectly normal to write about halachos as they come up, which is exactly what he does in shavuos and yevamos.